# Cannot get my figure placed at the right spot

Tags: floats, positioning

Although I use the option [H] or small case analogue of it [h], my figure is placed separately from the text how can I solve this issue? I tried to provide a minimal working example but this may not illustrate my problem since the document is much more complex than this cut-down version. The minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Soliton Evolution}
We begin our analysis by simulating the evolution of a third order soliton in the PCF Thorlabs NL-PM 750. This procedure of investigating soliton evolution is usually employed to test the accuracy of the code since solitons are analytical solutions of the NLSE, that is Eq.(\ref{eq:NLSE}).\cite{3} In order to conform with the analysis in the thesis and the article by the Dudley group we select the parameters corresponding to a third order soliton in our fiber\cite{thesis, 6}:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L_D &= \frac{T_{0}^{2}}{|\beta_2|}= 0.158242\ \si{\meter}\\
L_{NL}&=(\gamma P_0)^{-1}= 0.017602\ \si{\meter} \\
P_0& = 598\ \si{\watt} \\
N &= [L_D / L_{NL}]^{1/2} \cong 3 \\
Z_{soliton}&=(\frac{\pi}{2})L_D= 0.248566 \ \si{\meter}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[H]\capstart
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{SolitonEvolution(3rdOrder).jpg}
    \caption{The evolution of a third order soliton with the central wavelength of 790 \si{\nano\meter}.}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{SolitonEvolution(3rdOrder)Solperiod.jpg}
    \caption{The same soliton with the length scale expressed in terms of the soliton period.}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Soliton Fission}
When we introduce the Raman scattering into the NLSE by modifying it as follows:
The parameters selected correspond to a third order soliton and is the same as before.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The specifier `H` works properly when you load the package `float`: the float is put exactly after the preceding piece of code. Unfortunately, if there isn't enough space left on the page, the float is moved to the following page with whatever comes after it in the code, even if latex has to leave a huge blank space. See (http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf) for more info.

Comment: @PierPaolo Thanks for the comment I figured it out so I need to make sure that I have enough space. I also noticed that when the option h! is supplied it comes right after the text on a separate page, whereas when h is supplied it is put on a separate page of floats I presume. Is that correct?

Comment: You should never use `[h]` or even `[!h]` as it makes the float typically impossible to place, LaTeX will typically issue a warning and change it to `[ht]` to give a chance of finding a position but it is better really to use `[htp]` (or `[!htp]`) unless you really mean to prevent the float being placed on float pages or the top of a page.